# Recursive function with removing elements from input array as we go down the recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, algorithmic-trading, array-algorithms

I actually need all the combinations without duplicate in an array of k different possible elements. So e.g. [1,3,2,3,4,2,1] --> All the combinations including exactly once each number (1,2,3,4).

I have got a recursive function that's working perfectly fine, but with a massively big input array it takes too much time to run. That's why I would like to delete candidates from the input array as I progress in the recursion. As soon as I have a 2 in my combination, I can decrease the array by removing all the resting 2's. I cannot find a way of doing that without impacting the other recursion branches... Here follows the 100% working algorithm but it is not scalable... I'm looking for a way too enhance it by deleting as we go the input array.

```
static void maximalTimeRangeUtil( List<Integer> meta, List<Integer> opportunityMoments,List<Integer> stockTypes, List<Integer> momentsData, List <Integer> typesData, int start, int end, int index, int r) { 
        if (index == r) { 
                Set<Integer> same = new HashSet<Integer>(typesData);
                if(same.size()==typesData.size()) {
                    List<Integer> mins = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(int m=0; m<momentsData.size()-1 ;m++) {
                        mins.add(momentsData.get(m+1)-momentsData.get(m));
                    }
                    meta.add(Collections.min(mins));
                }
            return; 
        } 

        for (int i=start; i<=end && end-i+1 >= r-index; i++) { 
                typesData.set(index, stockTypes.get(i));
                momentsData.set(index, opportunityMoments.get(i));
            maximalTimeRangeUtil( meta,opportunityMoments, stockTypes, momentsData,typesData, i+1, end, index+1, r); 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question but why not just remove the duplicates from the list before you call your recursive method?

Comment: Because they are related to another array of the same length with all different number so they have an underlying different meaning

Comment: @ClémentGillet so you can't create a copy of the array without the duplicates?

Comment: Maybe you can just go through the array 24 times?

Comment: @Yola why would I do that ?

Comment: There are 24=4! different combinations from 4 elements.